# The remote end hung up unexpectedly errno10054

Tags: android-studio, github

I'm having trouble pushing changes I've made to Android Studio project on GitHub. It's giving me this error:

- Push failed
              Failed with error: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
              The remote end hung up unexpectedly
              RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
  I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have read permission of that git repo

Comment: Yes, I solved it. It was just a network error. Thanks!